# A special case of grouping coordinates

Tags: algorithm, grouping, coordinates

I'm trying to write a program to place students in cars for carpooling to an event. I have the addresses for each student, and can geocode each address to get coordinates (the addresses are close enough that I can simply use euclidean distances between coordinates.) Some of the students have cars and can drives others. How can I efficiently group students in cars? I know that grouping is usually done using algorithms like K-Mean, but I can only find algorithms to group N points into M arbitrary-sized groups. My groups are of a specific size and positioning. Where can I start? A simply greedy algorithm will ensure the first cars assigned have minimum pick-up distance, but the average will be high, I imagine.

Comment: Are you even looking to minimise the total distance travelled? I can see some student being fairly annoyed if, in order to minimise the total, one person ends up driving all over town.

Comment: I'm trying to most efficiently place students in cars. Part of the question involves figuring out exactly what that means, because I honestly can't say myself. It's for carpooling *to* some place, so I have a final destination as well, which could skew things. I want a better solution sitting down with an Excel sheet and Google Earth and having at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that you are trying to minimize the total distance traveled. Clearly traveling salesman problem is a special instance of your problem so your problem is NP-hard. That puts us in the heuristics/approximation algorithms domain.

The problem also needs some more specification, for example howmany students can fit in a given car. Lets say, as many as you want.

How about you solve it as a minimum spanning tree rooted at the final destination. Then each student with the car is is responsible for collecting all its children nodes. So the total distance traveled in at most 2x the total length of spanning tree which is a 2x bound right there. Of course this is ridiculous 'coz the nodes next to root will be driving a mega bus instead of a car in this case.

So then you start playing the packing game where you try to fill the cars greedily.

I know this is not a solution, but this might help you specify the problem better.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question, but since I found it, others will as well.

Group students together by distance. Find the distance between all sets of two students. Start with the closest students and add them in a group, and continue adding until all students are in groups. If students are beyond a threshold distance, like 50 miles, don't combine them into a group (this will cause a few students to go solo). If students have different sized cars, stop adding them when the max car size has been reached between the students in the group (and whichever one you're trying to add).

Finding the optimal (you asked for efficient) solution would require a more defined problem, which it seems like you don't have. If you wanted to eliminate individual drivers though, taking the above solution and special casing the outliers, working them individually into groups and swapping people around adjacent groups to fit them in, could find a very strong solution.